# Extract text before "[" in text

Tags: r, regex

I have a text file with product information as shown below

Sample file

```
  Id:   513954
    ASIN: 0789447096
      title: 1,000 Makers of the Millennium: The Men and Women Who Have Shaped the Last 1,000 Years
      group: Book
      salesrank: 831366
      similar: 0
      categories: 1
       |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Children's Books[4]|Ages 9-12[2786]|General[170063]
      reviews: total: 2  downloaded: 2  avg rating: 3.5
        2000-4-3  cutomer: A1PN4N5OC3GET7  rating: 5  votes:  11  helpful:   6
        2000-11-25  cutomer: A18C5AJ277PFVO  rating: 2  votes:  14  helpful:  14
```

Desired result

```
ASIN             V1  V2       V3                       V4             V5   V6
0789447096     Books Subjects Religion & Spirituality Christianity Clergy Preaching
```

So far

```
 library(stringr)    
    line <- "|Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Preaching[12368]"
       x <- str_split(line, fixed("|"))
ans <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", x)
ans <- gsub("\\d", "",ans)

[1]  "c      Books      Subjects      Religion   Spirituality      Christianity      Clergy      Preaching    "
```

extra "c" in result!
Also when i try with the actual file this doesnt work on it. how to do it?

```
products <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PhD/master/Expt/amazon.txt")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two small changes that I have done in your existing code.

You have to escape "|" (pipe) symbol as it means "**or**" in regular expression. Once you escape it. You will be able to take it literally. To remove "[ or ]" , the same thing again you have to do , you have to again escape them(its a representation of character class in regular expression).

so you can do is this:

```
    options(stringsAsFactors=F)
    rd <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PhD/master/Expt/amazon.txt")
rd1 <- data.frame(var = rd[grepl("\\||ASIN",rd)])

rd1$asin <- ifelse(grepl("ASIN", rd1$var)==T, rd1$var,NA)

rd1$asin <- zoo::na.locf(rd1$asin)

rd1 <- rd1[grepl("ASIN", rd1$var)==F,]

newlyst <- str_split(rd1[,"var"], "\\|") #updated line
max_len <- max(lengths(newlyst)) #updated line
newdf_inp <- lapply(newlyst, `length<-`, max_len) #updated line


df <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', newdf_inp)) #updated line
#head(df)

ans <- data.frame(sapply(df, function(x)gsub("\\[\\d+\\]", "", x)))
#head(ans)

ans1 <- sapply(ans, function(x) all(trimws(x)==""))
cbind(ASIN = rd1[,'asin'], ans[,!ans1]) ##Final Answer
```

**Output**:

```
> head(cbind(ASIN = rd1[,'asin'], ans[,!ans1]),2)
              ASIN    X2       X3               X4                 X5
1 ASIN: 0789447096 Books Subjects Children's Books          Ages 9-12
2 ASIN: 1582450099 Books Subjects    Home & Garden Animal Care & Pets
       X6     X7
1 General       
2    Dogs Breeds
```

**Updated output:**

```
> head(cbind(ASIN = rd1[,'asin'], ans[,!ans1])) ##Final Answer
              ASIN    X2               X3                      X4
1 ASIN: 0827229534 Books         Subjects Religion & Spirituality
2 ASIN: 0827229534 Books         Subjects Religion & Spirituality
3 ASIN: B00001ZSVK Music           Styles                     Pop
4 ASIN: B00001ZSVK Music           Styles                     R&B
5 ASIN: B00001ZSVK Music           Styles    Broadway & Vocalists
6 ASIN: B00001ZSVK Music Specialty Stores             Indie Music
                    X5      X6        X7   X8   X9  X10  X11
1         Christianity  Clergy Preaching <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2         Christianity  Clergy   Sermons <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3              General    <NA>      <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4              General    <NA>      <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
5             Musicals General      <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
6 Broadway & Vocalists    <NA>      <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: did you try on the actual file
products <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PhD/master/Expt/amazon.txt")

Comment: @pranavnerurkar updated my entire answer as per your needs. Thank you

Comment: only part missing in your result is the column of ASIN which i have mentioned in the desired output in the question

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PhD/master/Expt/sample.txt. @PKumar your answer doesnt work for this input. Can you help here

Comment: @pranavnerurkar, The link which you have pasted earlier in your question has different format , clearly you have to innovate , If you want to have a generic solution I guess its difficult , however I will try to improve the solution  which would fit in these case, but tomorrow if the format again changes , there is no gurantee. Thanks, wait for some time, will update the solution for given link :)

Comment: @pranavnerurkar , I am not sure what error you are getting at your end, please paste your error, I am getting results at my end

Comment: @pranavnerurkar  I have updated my code, I am running it at my end, I don't see any warning or error. Pls check at your end my friend

Comment: head(ans1) has ASIN blank and has 3 additional columns than it should have. additional coulmns have same information as first three coumns

Comment: @pranavnerurkar, so whatever extra column you , is because of the fact that some where in your records there are valid values, there is not additional columns at my end

Comment: @pranavnerurkar , please see the output and let me know what your expectation is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589553/extract-text-using-regex-in-r/50590842#50590842 -- could you help with this one too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172438/discussion-between-pkumar-and-pranav-nerurkar).